# Make main column wrap an oversized element floated in side column?

Tags: html, css

So i have this fiddle to demonstrate what I'm trying to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/vbqmq/28/

I have a two column layout but I want some elements in the main content to spill onto the side bar, and have the main content text wrap portion of the element that stays in the main content block.

The fiddle shows the desired layout, except that the content doesn't wrap the sidebar spill over.

I'm not attached to the current ordering in the HTML.  If I need to put it into the `container`, that's fine, but if I do that, the aside still needs to stay below the `cross-column` block.

Comment: I'm not quite following what you are saying. Can you please re-phrase this or provide a graphic of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @imakeitpretty - ScottS below provided this link: http://jsfiddle.net/vbqmq/37/  The bottom right shows the desired layout, however, I would like it if I could make the `cross-column` content not require a fixed size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Original Solution

Assuming your spillover is a set `width` and `height` (as your example), then a pseudo-element can be useful here. [See the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vbqmq/37/).

```css
#content:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    float: right;
    width: 50px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

### More Flexible Solution

The only way I know to gain flexibility in dimensions is to move the items into the content area. [See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vbqmq/41/). So this html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="main">
    <div id="container">
      <div id="content">    
        <div id="cross-columns"></div>    
        <div id="aside"></div>
        <p>Main content follows</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

With some margin tweaks to your original css:

```css
#cross-columns{
    margin: -10px -160px 0 0;
}

#aside{
    margin-right: -160px;
}
```

Comment: Well, the fixed size was really just to make a block.  Ideally it wouldn't be fixed width, but I could design my content to a fixed width.

Comment: @EricG--you can make it more flexible, but not without changing the html. See my revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not 100% sure what you are asking, but I know that this little jquery plugin will wrap text around any shape which is pretty cool.

```
http://baconforme.com/
```